# If Empty, Looping Function in Do While

Tags: arrays, loops, do-while

I got problem on my code...

What i want is,

$r is array, can be empty or not (dynamic)

**if $r(array) empty** repeat the fucntion until the result of **$r(array) not empty**

so far my code like this, but sometime still give me result the empty

```
    do {
        $r = get_pht_desc($wordString);
    }
    while (count($r) <= 0);

    print_r ($r);
```

Comment: if `$r` is empty then loop will continue infinite...

Comment: Maybe `get_pht_desc` function get `Stirng` sometimes.

Comment: No... `get_pht_desc` the result always array